# ASP.Net data table to excel shows date time format issue

Tags: asp.net, export-to-excel

When am creating excel from datatatble in asp.net date time format is wrong. I just convert date time to 'dd-MM-yyyy', if the date is   greater than 12 , it would write correctly , otherwise it would be mm-dd-yyyy format. Actuall am writing '01-11-2016' ie November 1st, but it shows '11-01-2016' in excel. My code is like this. Give me a solution.

```
        int rowsTotal = 0, colsTotal = 0;
        int i, j, k;
        rowsTotal = dt.Rows.Count;
        colsTotal = dt.Columns.Count;
        for (i = 0; i <= rowsTotal - 1; i++)
        {
            k = 0;
            for (j = 0; j <= colsTotal - 1; j++)
            {
                if (gv.    Columns[j].Visible)
                {
                    if (dt.Columns[j].DataType.Name == "DateTime")
                    {
                        DateTime dtDate = new DateTime();
                        excelWorksheet.Cells[i + 4, k + 1] = string.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", dt.Rows[i][j] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i][j]) : dt.Rows[i][j]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        excelWorksheet.Cells[i + 4, k + 1] = dt.Rows[i][j];
                    }
                    k += 1;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Update your usage of `string.Format` to take a `IFormatProvider`, such as `string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", dt.Rows[i][j] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i][j]) : dt.Rows[i][j]);`

Comment: Its not working, Actually upto date value 12 itself date time format is wrong, after that correct 'dd-MM-yyyy' format is working. Plz help

Comment: Have you checked the cell format in Excel to make sure it represents the correct data format?

Comment: Actually its a protected excel template. Used for eReturn . So we cant change the cell format manually. Am using windows server 2008 for deploy. Any dependency ? while exporting gridview to excel also shows the same issue for date field.